# how to get divs to display one at a time, set to a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have been playing with setInterval and setTimeout to get one div to display before moving on to get the second div to display and then the third (final). After the final div displays I want to loop back to the first div to begin the process of toggling the divs again.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  $(".one").toggle(); 
  $(".two").toggle();

}, 5000);
```

So I find that this loop works really well but when I introduce the ".third" div it skips the second and I am super confused!!

Comment: well the idea is to toggle/switch/replace.... but i get the impression that its not supposed to work outside of two values

Answer (score 3):

Give them all the same class, and use a counter variable that you increment each time to know which one to show. Use modulus to wrap around when you reach the last div.

```js
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  $(".class").hide();
  $(".class").eq(counter).show();
  counter = (counter + 1) % $(".class").length;
}, 2000);
```

```css
.class {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class">
  Div 1
</div>
<div class="class">
  Div 2
</div>
<div class="class">
  Div 3
</div>
<div class="class">
  Div 4
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate over your divs otherwise you are just toggling all of them every 5000ms, which might seem to work for only two divs, but not gonna work for more

pseudocode:

```
var divs = [$(".one"),$(".two"),$(".three")]
var index = 0
function focusNextDiv(){
  //hide all divs
  //select divs[index] and toggle it
  //increment index by 1
  //check if index is bigger than divs.length if so reset index to 0
}
setInterval(function(){ 
  focusNextDiv()
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for this one DavidIrnt, this is something i tried but i did not understand how to loop it

Comment: how can I get an "indicator" element to show that the indexed div is being displayed? I tried piggybacking on the var index and using a new array... but that didnt work